# Sorting a with databinding colorized datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, data-binding, datagrid

I recently tried to colorize certain rows in a `datagrid` with the following code (XAML) :

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:IsDateExpiredConverter x:Key="IsDateExpiredConverter" />
    <Style x:Key="DataGridRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Notenmeldung, Converter={StaticResource IsDateExpiredConverter}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#d2efbd"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

The method:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(DateTime), typeof(bool))]
public class IsDateExpiredConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (DBNull.Value == value)
            return false;

        DateTime date = (DateTime)value;
        DateTime curDate = DateTime.Now;


        if (date < curDate)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

So what it does, it just colorizes the DataGridRow where "*Notenmeldung*" is < than the current date. This works just fine.

### The Problem

When I click on the header to sort my grid, sometimes the green of the row disappers. This depends on the column I'm sorting and the direction I'm sorting. For example, I sort one column in both directions and everything is fine. Another one just shows the color (the row is still there) when I am sorting in one specific direction (in the other direction it gets green again). And then we also have the case that nothing gets green anymore. The source of the `DataGrid` is a `DataBaseTable` and I don't see any regularity between datatypes and the content of the cells.

---

I really appreciate every small hint.

Comment: Try to put your Resources as `<DataGrid.Resources>` and remove the `x:key` from the style

Comment: @lokusking VS says, that DataGrid.Resources doesnt exists or isn't accessable. Anything I could've overseen?

Comment: I suppose you have a DataGrid? Put your resources in there instead of `<Window.Resources>`. If you need a hint i can make an Answer to show you what i mean

Comment: @lokusking Yes, that would be really helpful. :)

Comment: Since you stated, that there was no change with my code, do you use some kind of special binding? Maybe show the XAML of your DataGrid too

Comment: @lokusking My AlternatingRowBackgrounds did overwrite the color... Thats interesting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution:

Don't use `AlternatingRowBackground`, this overwrites the changed color.